# Monodevelop not opening

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

When I double click a script monodevelop isn't opening, but I can open monodevelop separately and then load projectname.sln file and it syncs ok. I can also call external editor, but I'd like to use monodevelop for code completion. Anyone managed to get this working?
I have mono-4.0.3-gtksharp-2.12.26-win32-0.msi and 
gtk-sharp-2.12.26.msi installed, and I am using
Windows 7.

Comment: Which script r u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, Monodevelop is not associated with Unity. Go under `Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools` and see if Monodevelop is selected as external script editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem very similar to yours and what I did to fix this was I downloaded the needed GTK# file from the Installer in Program Files>Unity> MonoDevelop> GTKSharp.( If prompted, Delete old GTK file and Re-Install GTK.) Then enter Unity and go to Edit>Preferences>External Tools>External Script Editor and Make Sure it is set to "MonoDevelop (Built-In)". Another thing that may help (I don't know if it 100% works) is to Install the .NET from [MonoDevelop's Site](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/).  Also MAKE SURE UNITY IS FULLY INSTALLED! What my first problem was , it was that the Unity download would stop downloading because in task manager(CTRL+ALT+DEL>Task Manager)  The "Windows Modules Installer" was running, so you have to end this task. And all of the files ( including the MonoDevelop file folder) will be there after the installation is done. Hope This Helped!